# Understanding a proof of: If $N\unlhd G$ s.t. $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable, then $G$ is solvable.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups, quotient-group, solvable-groups

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ s.t. $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable, then $G$ is solvable.

Proof:

Because $N$, $G/N$ are solvable $\Rightarrow$ $N^{(s)}=\{e\}$, $(G/N)^{(t)}=\{e\}$ for $s,t\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $G/N$ is a homomorphic image of $G$ (under $\psi: G\rightarrow G/N$), we have that $(G/N)^{(n)}=G^{(n)}N/N$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus, $G^{(t)}\subseteq N$ and therefore $G^{(s+t)}\subseteq N^{s}=\{e\}$ and $G$ is solvable.

---

I don't understand the part where $(G/N)^{(n)}=G^{(n)}N/N$ and I also don't get why we can say $G^{(t)}\subseteq N$.

I hope someone can help clearing this up for me.

For original source, follow [this link](https://books.google.at/books?id=hiQ8e0b48swC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=image%20is%20solvable&source=bl&ots=skG0yjaVeK&sig=ACfU3U1OtCvWg1oN9p0clFv9Jgrkv7DeAg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXkpDEuJP1AhVwgv0HHTRHAsoQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=image%20is%20solvable&f=false) (Theorem 2.1)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177867/if-n-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g-with-n-and-g-n-solvable-prove-that-g-i) for details. What means $(G/N)^{(t)}=1$? It means $G^{(t)}\subseteq N$.

Comment: The OP is asking for help with a particular proof, @SeanEberhard. That is no duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should proceed by a small example: let's start with the first derivative, namely $(G/N)'=G'N/N$. How do you prove this? Well just write it out:
$$(G/N)'=\langle [\overline{x},\overline{y}]: \overline{x},\overline{y} \in G/N \rangle \\=\langle [x,y]N: x,y \in G \rangle \\=\langle [x,y]: x,y \in G \rangle N \\=G'N/N.$$
And $G'N/N=\overline{1}$ if and only if $G'N=N$ if and only if $G' \subseteq N$. Now this should help you for the higher derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One last question: What's the logic between the step $\langle [x,y]N: x,y \in G \rangle =\langle [x,y]: x,y \in G \rangle N =G'N/N$? I feel like the term in the middle isn't equal to the other two? Other than that, I can carry on from here, thanks

Comment: Well if you do the derivative in $G/N$, then $[\overline{x},\overline{y}]=x^{-1}Ny^{-1}NxNyN=[x,y]N$. This also shows that you can take out the $N$ in the first expression.